# Check for all frames to load

Tags: puppeteer

I would like to check that all frames on a page have been loaded. I can't quite figure this out, and part of that is I don't fully understand the frame events (specifically when exactly do `frameattached` and `framenavigated` events fire?).

Here is what I am doing right now, but I'm binding to the same page event several times rather than a frame event.

```
function waitForFrames() {
  return Promise.all(page.frames().map((frame) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      page.on('framenavigated', resolve);
    });
  })).then(() => {
    console.log('Frames loaded');
  })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e.message);
    });
}
```

How can I check that all frames are loaded?

Comment: maybe this one can help:
https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051

Answer (score 2):

The [Puppeteer Documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-frame) for the Frame class helps explain the frame events:

> #### class: Frame
>
> At every point of time, page exposes its current frame tree via the [`page.mainFrame()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagemainframe) and [`frame.childFrames()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#framechildframes) methods.
>
> [Frame](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-frame) object's lifecycle is controlled by three events, dispatched on the page object:
>
> - [`'frameattached'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-frameattached) - fired when the frame gets attached to the page. A Frame can be attached to the page only once.
> - [`'framenavigated'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-framenavigated) - fired when the frame commits navigation to a different URL.
> - [`'framedetached'`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#event-framedetached) - fired when the frame gets detached from the page. A Frame can be detached from the page only once.

---

You can wait for a frame (by name) using the following function:

```
const wait_for_frame = (page, frame_name) => {
  let fulfill_promise;
  const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill_promise = x);
  
  check_frame();
  
  return promise;
  
  const check_frame = () => {
    const frame = page.frames().find(current_frame => current_frame.name() === frame_name);
    
    if (frame) {
      fulfill_promise(frame);
    } else {
      page.once('frameattached', check_frame);
    }
  };
};

// Waiting for frame to become attached:
const frame = await wait_for_frame(page, frame_name);

// Waiting for frame to contain a certain selector:
await frame.waitForSelector(selector);

const button = await frame.$(selector);

button.click();
```

<sub>The above code snippet was influenced by and improved on from: [Source](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1361#issuecomment-343748051).</sub>

---

Finally, you can loop through and [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) the frames one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Using Grant's solution I ran into the problem, that the iFrame I'm looking for sometimes gets detached after pageload and then (re-)attached and navigated. In this case the waitForSelector produces an exception "iFrame got detached". It seems to me that a frame appearing in page.frames() is not guaranteed to actually be attached.

So I changed the wait_for_frame function of his solution to cover this case. This also covers the case when there are multiple iFrames on the page.

```
const wait_for_frame = (page, frame_name) => {

    const check_frame = frame => {
        if (frame.name() == frame_name) {
            fulfill_promise(frame);
            page.off('framenavigated', check_frame);
        }
    };
    
    let fulfill_promise;
    const promise = new Promise(x => fulfill_promise = x);
    page.on('framenavigated', check_frame);
  
    return promise;
};

// Waiting for frame to become attached:
const frame = await wait_for_frame(page, frame_name);

// Waiting for frame to contain a certain selector:
await frame.waitForSelector(selector);

const button = await frame.$(selector);

button.click();
```